# I extended User Model and I don't know how to get value of it from other users through forms

Tags: python, django

I extended User Model so I made nickname.

And nickname appears on admin page but I can't get value of it from other users through forms.

The value was not saved whenever I clicked the submit button of my signup page after I filled up nickname charfield.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class Profile(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'profile'
        verbose_name_plural = u'profile'
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    nick = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'nickname', max_length=50, blank=True,)
```

I think it's working good.

```
#forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from .models import Profile

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    nick = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "nick", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CreateUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.nick = self.cleaned_data["nick"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

But I think something is wrong with forms.py

```
<!--signup.html-->
{% extends 'moc/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'signup' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The nick field is on the profile, not the user. You need to create that related instance along with the user.

```
    user = super(CreateUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    profile = Profile(user=user)
    profile.nick = self.cleaned_data["nick"]
    if commit:
        user.save()
        profile.save()
```